# G Suite - Allow public to send mails to a group alias

Tags: google-groups, google-workspace-for-business

I have recently started using G Suite for my business email addresses. I am trying to set up a support@ email with multiple members by using Google Groups.

How can I allow anyone outside of the organization to send email messages to an alias that will be forwarded to multiple members? I do not have the option to choose "Public" when setting the post permissions in my group.

Comment: Under Groups Settings > Basic Settings> Post, you don't see an "Anyone on the web" setting?

Answer (score 4):

For G Suite, you can configure a group to accept emails from anyone, but you can't do it at groups.google.com (where you configure most group settings). Instead:

- Visit admin.google.com, sign in
- Click the "Groups" tile
- Hover over the group you want to change and click the "edit settings" link that appears

At this point you'll see a permissions grid that allows you to pick from a set of default access types (public, restricted, etc). From here:

- Click the edit button (pencil, top right)
- Click "Team" to set some reasonable defaults
- Click the button at the intersection of "Publish posts" and "External"
- Click "Save" (bottom right)

[image: The button to click to enable public posting on a G Suite Google Group]